# Interpreting a linear map as a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

"Let $E$ and $F$ be bases ( not canonical ones ) of $\Bbb{R^n}$ and $\Bbb{R^m}$. Show that the matrix $A_{EF}$ of linear mapping $L$ with respect to bases $E$ and $F$ can be computed as a matrix product $$A_{EF}=T^{-1}A_L S$$

what are the matrices $T$ and $S$?"

I suppose it is implicit that $L:\Bbb{R^n} \to \Bbb{R^m}$ in this case. Computing $A_{EF}$ itself is not too difficult. Let $E=\{e_1, ... ,e_n\}$ and $F=\{f_1, ..., f_m\}$. Now compute $L(e_i)$ for each basis vector, then interpret them as linear combinations with respect to basis $F$ ( they are in $\Bbb{R^m})$. If we do this for each $1\leq i \leq n$, we have a set of $n$ coordinate vectors. The matrix $A_{EF}$ is found by transposing said coordinates vectors as the columns of this matrix. I guess the idea, is to show this process is equivalent to some matrix product.

A few things can be worked out from the given equation. Suppose we multiply $T^{-1}A_L S$ ( rightwise ) by some $\bar{x} \in \Bbb{R^n}$. So matrix $S$ must have $n$ columns. $A_L$ is probably the matrix of $L$ with respect to the canonical bases. $T$ is invertible, so its likely a change of coordinates/basis matrix ( since they are always invertible ). My hypothesis, is that this matrix product takes a vector in $\Bbb{R^n}$, changes its coordinates ( ... so they are in respect to basis $E$ ), gives the linear image $L(\bar{x})$ and finally changes these coordinates so they are in respect to basis $F$. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: $T$ and $S$ are change of coordinates matrices between the canonical basis and $F$ and $E$ respectively. $A_L$ should indeed be the matrix of $L$ in the canonical basis on both sides

Comment: Your final description is off. $A_L$ operates on canonical coordinates, while $A_{EF}$ operates on the $E$ and $F$ coordinate systems. So $S$ has to convert $E$ coordinates to canonical $\Bbb R^n$ coordinates that $A_L$ can act on. $T$ likewise converts $F$ coordinates to canonical $\Bbb R^m$ coordinates, so its inverse converts the canonical coordinates that $A_L$ produces into $F$ coordinates.